# How to programmatically get the height & width of one ImageView and set it to another ImageView in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

Here is the code

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@color/white" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/first_imageview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:src="@drawable/frame" />

  <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/second_imageview"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignTop="@id/first_imageview"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@id/first_imageview"         
     android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now i need to detect the height & width of `first_imageview` and then set it to `second_image_view`. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set

```
android:layout_alignRight="@id/inside_imageview"
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/inside_imageview"
```

This will ensure that second image view has same size as first one.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
second_image_view.getLayoutParams().height = first_image_view.getHeight();
second_image_view.getLayoutParams().width = first_image_view.getWidth();
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code should do it:

```
secondImageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                         firstImageView.getWidth(), firstImageView.getHeight()));
```

And if you wish to use xml to do so, you can follow Chitranshu answer.